# 16 A mains breaker and heat

Tags: mains, circuit-breaker

So I got curious and could not find any good information on high breaker load over an extended period.

In my home (in EU, 240V) there is a breaker which is rated for 16 A. If 16 A is drawn for hours on end to charge an EV, the breaker gets very hot.

Would it be safe to draw 16 A for, say, 12 hours on end?

I found the [product info](https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/A9D67416) with a datasheet.

Comment: *Would it be safe to draw 16A for, say, 12 hours on end?* No because that is too close to the limit of the circuit breaker but more importantly: **the wiring in your house.** Think about what it would cost to replace a failed 16 A breaker versus the cost of replacing 16 A because it overheated (ignoring the fact that your house might burn down).

Comment: The circuit breaker is rated for 16 A because that is what the wiring is designed to handle. If you want an outlet capable of handling 16 A for an extended time then you will need thicker wiring and a breaker with a higher rating. For example, 25 A wiring and 25 A breaker.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The wire is 5 x 6mm2.

Comment: To whoever downvoted my question, how can I improve it?

Comment: *The wire is 5 x 6mm2* congratulations, that tells me nothing. The dimensions of a wire still don't guarantee current handling capability, the material is also important. The rating of **everything** needs to be > 16A before you can safely use it at 16 A. There's a 16 A breaker there, someone decided that that was needed instead of a higher rated breaker.

Comment: *16 A ...the breaker gets very hot* + *Would it be safe to draw 16A* You don't think that the answer is already obvious? Would you expect anyone here to say "That's perfectly safe mate, no worries!" suppose you would take that (bad) advice, next day your house burns down. Who is to blame?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I get the feeling that you are angry with me for asking a question about something I do not know anything about. If you need more information, just ask me. I will happily improve my question however I am able.

Comment: To my knowledge the breaker *could be* designed to get hot - that's one of the things that causes it to trip (there is also an instant magnetic trip for extremely high current)

Comment: (I would think that just part of the breaker on the inside would get hot, that you couldn't feel on the outside, but I'm not a breaker designer, so maybe you can feel it on the outside)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have not studied power distribution component ratings in Europe, but in North America, the ratings are quite conservative. Over here, a 15 amp breaker is designed to operate at 15 amps 24-7 for many years without  failure or tripping. I believe that the ambient temperature ratings are quite conservative as well. Do you have manufacturer and safety standards information to back up your claim?

Comment: @CharlesCowie *Over here, a 15 amp breaker is designed to operate at 15 amps 24-7 for many years without failure or tripping.* OK, but then I consider that breaker as only protecting against a **short circuit**. When a 15 A breaker is used, what then protects the wiring against **overloading**? Here in EU, a 16 A breaker/fuse is supposed to protect against short circuit **and** overloading (for a limited time 16 A is OK but for sure not 24/7).

Comment: @Heki You should mention what your location is, my comments apply mostly for the situation in the EU with 240 V AC. In the US with 120 V AC, things might be different. If you're in EU, drawing 16 A through a 16 breaker is not OK. In the US it might be OK.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sure. I have updated the question. I live in the EU too. Perhaps if I can find a datasheet, that would be helpful?

Comment: @@Bimpelrekkie Over here, wire ampacity is quite conservative also. The breakers do protect the wiring.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Usually the tripping time of CB has no defined value for I=In, therefore a 16A CB shouldn't trip if the load is 16A constant, also here in EU.

Comment: A 16 amp _fuse_ could literally run 24/7 for _months_ on 17 amps without blowing. Therefore, wiring must support a higher current than fuse rating without starting a fire. The rules for wires protected by circuit breakers _may_ be different. But if the same, 16 amps through a 16 amp rated circuit breaker should not cause a fire if wiring is OK. The danger indicated by your question is not whether 16 amps is safe for 16 amp wiring, but whether circuit breaker is faulty. The temperature may or may not be normal.

Comment: You should be able to draw 16 A continuously on a 16 A circuit breaker in the EU. How hot is hot? Some heating is expected, warm but not hot I would say.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Just for curiosity, what maximum continuous load current do you recommend for a B16A breaker?

Comment: @winny Certainly, I would expect it to get warm, but I can only really press my fingers down on the plastic shell for a few seconds before it starts to be unpleasant. I would venture a guess and say somewhere around 60C.

Comment: Could be that you have a bad breaker, EN norms non withstanding. I would just try to replace the breaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the data printed on the front of the breaker, you should be able to find the manufacturer's data sheet.

The breakers used in the EU are designed never to break when run at the rated current. They require at least a small overload before they trip.

The data sheet only requires that the ambient temperature should be no more than 40C. So unless it's packed in with other hot breakers, it should be fine to run indefinitely.

It's worth checking all the connections to the breaker. Including any bus bar if your panel uses one.

Comment: I managed to find the datasheet. See my edit.

Comment: @Heki the only limitation I can see in the data sheet is that the ambient temperature should be no more than 40C.  So unless it's packed in with other hot breakers, it should be fine.

Comment: I ran it for two hours yesterday at full load. The top got really hot, still guessing 60C, but the bottom was quite cold in comparison, almost room temperature. I might have someone check the top connections, but it seems like it is okay. The power draw is just faintly audible when I hold my head close to the breaker.

Comment: By the way, if you can add your comment to your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A circuit breaker has a bi-metallic element that is heated from wires carrying current. This bi-metal when too hot engages a lever that trips the CB. There is also a magnetic part of the CB, this engages the lever if the current becomes instantly very high - short circuit. In case of short circuit the bi-metal would take too long to heat, bend, trigger.

You have a RCBO which additionally measures residual current, but this is not causing heat.

So, if your load current is very close to the CB rating, then a higher heat generation is to be expected. But there are also other causes of CB oveheating, most common is bad wire connection. Also an option but less probable is a malfunctioning device.

If I understood, you have 5x6mm^2 outgoing cable. For such cross section a CB of 25A (or even 32A) would be appropriate. But first it has to be found out why a 16A was chosen.

[Image source](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/miniature-circuit-breakers-mcbs-for-beginners)

[image]